# Problem in parsing JSON data using volley library

Tags: android, android-studio, methods, android-asynctask, synchronization

This is a simple program to gain the JSON data from the internet.  **answerWithAsyncTask()** is an interface that ensures that all the downloaded data will only be added to **questionArrayList** when the download is complete.

Error:    java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0

```
 private List<Question> questionList;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//Few findViewbyId's here. Ignoring them

        questionList = new QuestionBank().getQuestions(new answerWithAsyncTask() {
            @Override
            public void asyncMe(ArrayList<Question> questionArrayList) {

                questionTextview.setText(questionArrayList.get(currentQuestionIndex).getQuestionId());
            }
        });
                 updateQuestion();     //This is the newly added line
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.prev_button:
                updateQuestion();
                break;
        }
    }
    private void updateQuestion() {
        String question = questionList.get(1).getQuestionId();
        questionTextview.setText(question);
    }
```

**UPDATE** This is my **getQuestions** method.

```
String url ="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/curiousily/simple-quiz/master/script/statements-data.json";
    private ArrayList<Question> questionArrayList= new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Question> getQuestions (final answerWithAsyncTask callback){
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest =new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, (String) null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++){
                            Question question = new Question();
                            try {
                                question.setQuestionId(response.getJSONArray(i).getString(0));
                                question.setTorF(response.getJSONArray(i).getBoolean(1));
                                questionArrayList.add(question);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        if(null != callback) callback.asyncMe(questionArrayList);
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    }
                });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonArrayRequest);
        return questionArrayList;
    }
```

and this my interface **answerWithAsyncTask**

```
public interface answerWithAsyncTask {
    void asyncMe(ArrayList<Question> arrayList);
}
```

Comment: In your method updateQuestion() change - get(1) to get(0). And then tell me if it works or not?

Comment: No, it does not. Actually the no of data parsed through JSON array is more than 900. So, it should show a value irrespective of the 0 or 1.

Comment: For example in the first case, if write instead ``get(50)`` it would still show me the data correspondingly. But in the second case any value leads to the error.

Comment: Index: 1, Size: 0 means the size of your ArrayList is 0. The line where you're trying to access its elements, you should first check it's size by logging.

Comment: Actually I have abstracted the remaining code. Volley is asynchronous, that means it will show the data before even the datas are downloaded from the internet, and that's why I have used the **answerWithAsyncTAsk()** inner interface so as to maintain a type of delegation here(only show data when completely received).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting this error because

```
 private List<Question> questionList;
```

is empty. In your first code, you are not getting any error because you are not calling updateQuestion() which will try to fetch data from an empty list. The error is in 2nd code because it's trying to access that empty list. Your

```
 return questionArrayList;
```

is not returning data to questionList. Here, you are trying to do interface callback, to implement it properly, please look at this answer and change your code accordingly,
[Java Interface Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63740596/java-classes-and-interface-combination/63745009#63745009)